# Why logs both of console and file?

Tags: java, logging

I'm using Java util logging and getting logger object via this code:

```
public static Logger getLoggerForMemberSaving(Class<?> clazz) {
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(clazz.getName());
        try {
            Handler fileHandler = new FileHandler("./oneMemberSaving.log");
            Formatter simpleFormatter = new SimpleFormatter();
            fileHandler.setFormatter(simpleFormatter);
            logger.addHandler(fileHandler);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "An error occured while getting logger object. Error is:" + ex.getMessage());
        }
        return logger;
    }
```

And, I'm using the logger object like this:

```
public void addOneMember(Member member) {
        Logger LOGGER = LoggingUtil.getLoggerForMemberSaving(this.getClass());
        try {
            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "One member adding method is running!");
            memberRepository.save(member);
            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Member saving is successfull. Member info is:" + member);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "An error occured while saving member. Error is:" + ex.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

When I run addOneMember method, the logs at the IDE console and in the file. But I want to see log messages only in the log file.

How can I do this? How can I prevent logging to the IDE console?

Comment: Probably you have tio remove default handler firstl.

Comment: @Antoniossss , as mentioned in duplicate post, LogManager.getLogManager().reset(); code line solved the problem. Thank you everyone.